# AsyncGraphMachine used with async on_enter callbacks

Tags: pytransitions

My question is actually pretty simple, but I am not well versed in pytransition code to find the answer by myself:

Is is possible to use AsyncGraphMachine with async on_enter callbacks only.

In the documentation: https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions#-using-async-callbacks
it is stated that:

> If you are using Python 3.7 or later, you can use AsyncMachine to work
> with asynchronous callbacks. You can mix synchronous and asynchronous
> callbacks if you like but this may have undesired side effects. Note
> that events need to be awaited and the event loop must also be handled
> by you.

I am using python > 3.7, and I cannot make my samples to work:

```
from transitions.extensions.asyncio import AsyncMachine
import asyncio
import time
from transitions import State


class AsyncModel:

    async def do_async(self):
        print("Do async start")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print("Do async end")

    def do_sync(self):
        print("Do async start")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Do async end")

transitions = [dict(trigger="start", source="*", dest="initialization"),
               dict(trigger="finish", source="initialization", dest="final")]
states = [State(name="initialization", on_enter=["do_async", "do_sync"]),
          State(name="final", on_enter=["do_async", "do_sync"])]

model = AsyncModel()
machine = AsyncMachine(model, states=states, transitions=transitions)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(model.start())
```

The actual error is:

```
    /home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transitions/core.py:128: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncMachine.callbacks' was never awaited
      event_data.machine.callbacks(self.on_enter, event_data)       RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback       Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./test.py", line 27, in <module>
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(model.start())
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
        return future.result()
      File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transitions/extensions/asyncio.py", line 177, in trigger
        return await self.machine.process_context(func, _model)
      File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transitions/extensions/asyncio.py", line 409, in process_context
        res = await self._process(func, model)
      File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transitions/extensions/asyncio.py", line 443, in _process
        return await trigger()
      File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transitions/extensions/asyncio.py", line 192, in _trigger
        return await self._process(event_data)
      File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transitions/extensions/asyncio.py", line 201, in _process
        if await trans.execute(event_data):
      File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transitions/extensions/asyncio.py", line 130, in execute
        await self._change_state(event_data)
      File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transitions/extensions/asyncio.py", line 145, in _change_state
        await event_data.machine.get_state(self.dest).enter(event_data)         TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

However, on_enter type of function are callbacks, according to the documentation itself: https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions#state-callbacks

So I wonder what is going on here.

Thank you in advance for your help

EDIT: ok the problem might even be somewhere I wouldn't even have considered:

```
from transitions.extensions.asyncio import AsyncMachine
import asyncio
import time
from transitions import State


class AsyncModel:

    async def do_async(self):
        print("Do async start")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print("Do async end")

    def do_sync(self):
        print("Do sync start")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Do sync end")

transitions = [dict(trigger="start", source="initialization", dest="final", before=["do_async", "do_sync"], after=["do_sync"], prepare=["do_sync"])]
states = [State(name="initialization"),
          State(name="final")]

model = AsyncModel()
machine = AsyncMachine(model, states=["initialization", "final"], transitions=transitions, initial="initialization")

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(model.start())
```

This is working, however this is failing:

```
from transitions.extensions.asyncio import AsyncMachine
import asyncio
import time
from transitions import State


class AsyncModel:

    async def do_async(self):
        print("Do async start")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print("Do async end")

    def do_sync(self):
        print("Do sync start")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Do sync end")

transitions = [dict(trigger="start", source="initialization", dest="final", before=["do_async", "do_sync"], after=["do_sync"], prepare=["do_sync"])]
states = [State(name="initialization"),
          State(name="final")]

model = AsyncModel()
machine = AsyncMachine(model, states=states, transitions=transitions, initial="initialization")

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(model.start())
```

Looks like vanilla states from transitions are not compatible with async machines, you should rather use "from transitions.extensions.asyncio import AsyncState" instead

Answer (score 0):

Ok so actually I found the answer by trial and error, my issue was that I was using State instead of AsyncState